# UserControl src change in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, user-controls

I have a index.aspx page with

```
<AHD_MPC:AHDMainPageControl1 id="AHDControl" runat="server">
                </AHD_MPC:AHDMainPageControl1>
```

and defined/loaded on the same.

```
 <%@ Register Src="UserControl/AHDControl1.ascx" TagName="AHDMainPageControl1" TagPrefix="AHD_MPC" %>
```

On the first load AHDControl1.ascx will get loaded. 
Now i have a button on index.aspx page....on click of that i want to load the AHDControl2.ascx on the same location and hide/destroy the AHDControl1.ascx from that location....apart from CSS show/hide option, any other way to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate both controls on the page, start Control1 with `Visible = true`; and Controle2 with `Visible = false`. When you want to toggle the visibility, do so in the code behind tied to the `button_Click` event.

Comment: i am looking for another option beside css if possible

Comment: This is not a css-based solution. When you set `Visible=false` for a control, it is not rendered on the page by ASP.net. No css is used.

Comment: This is the simplest way to do it. You do not need any dynamic loading when `Visible` will do the trick.